# getting the inner text of a node

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble getting the inner text of a particular node. I have added the example node I am working with and the javascript I have come up with. The javascript works as far as returning this `<span id="goal_left">3 goals lect</span>` if i log it to the console. If i add `innerText` to the javascript examples it will return nothing to the console. Any ideas how to get this text?

html

```
<span id="goal_left">3 goals lect</span>
```

javascript: these examples return `<span id="goal_left">3 goals lect</span>`

```
document.getElementById("goal_left");

document.querySelectorAll("span#goal_left")[0];
```

javascript: these examples return nothing

```
document.getElementById("goal_left").innerText;

document.querySelectorAll("span#goal_left")[0].innerText;
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Probably the easiest way:

```
document.querySelectorAll("span#goal_left")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Though if you always want the first node returned by `querySelectorAll()` you could simply use:

```
document.querySelector("span#goal_left").firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Incidentally, I'd imagine any browser that implements `querySelectorAll()`probably implements `textContent`, giving:

```
document.querySelector("span#goal_left").textContent;
```

Just to offer a cross-browser option:

```
var textProperty = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText';
document.getElementById('goal_left')[textProperty]
```

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=innertext
Implementation on IE is the same for both of them, so I doubt this is cross-browser below IE11

Answer (score 1):

The `innerHTML` property might be what you're looking for. It holds the HTML code inside an element as string.

Comment: i tried innerHTML but it doesn't return anything to the console

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementById("goal_left").innerHTML  instead of innerText.

Also you might want to use jQuery for manipulating DOM elements, it's much easier and less error prone.

Comment: i tried innerHTML but it doesn't return anything to the console

Comment: It worked for me on Chrome, try var aa = document.getElementById("goal_left").innerHTML; and console.log(aa);