# Selecting elements with querySelector

Tags: javascript, json, css-selectors

```
<div id="~" class="dm-post-0 well clearfix post listview"
    data-identifier="~" data-relative="https://url_that_i_want_to_capture"
    data-feed="~">

let convertEntries = () => {
  "use strict";
  let target = [...document.getElementsByClassName("listview")];
  let result = [];
  target.forEach((element) => {
    result.push({
      title: element.querySelector(".list-header strong").textContent,
      url: element.querySelector("#listview").dataset.relative,
    });
  });
  return result;
};
```

I can now capture just the text within the `strong` tag. However, I cannot capture the `data-relative` attribute.

Comment: `.getAttribute("data-relative")` or `.dataset.relative`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the values of data attributes in JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760520/how-can-i-get-the-values-of-data-attributes-in-javascript-code)

Comment: `var element=document.querySelector("strong").innerText;` or `var element=document.querySelector(".list-header strong").innerText;`

Comment: `const test = document.querySelector("strong").textContent` (`.innerText` is widely supported, but not standard, use `.textContent` instead)

Comment: Duplicate for the first question (although asking multiple questions is frowned upon): [getting the inner text of a node](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11745355/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this `var element = document.querySelector(".list-header strong").textContent;` to get the text inside the strong element inside your list-header class and `var element2 = document.querySelector(".listview").getAttribute('data-relative');` to get the attribute

```js
var element = document.querySelector(".list-header strong").textContent;
var element2 = document.querySelector(".listview").getAttribute('data-relative');
console.log(element);
console.log(element2);
```

```html
<div class="pull-left list-header" dir="ltr">
  <strong>[Text that I want to capture</strong>
  <span> - [Text that I want to exclude]</span>
</div>

<div id="~" class="dm-post-0 well clearfix post listview" data-identifier="~" data-relative="https://url_that_i_want_to_capture" data-feed="~">
```

Comment: .innerText is widely supported, but not standard, use .textContent instead

Comment: `data-*` attributes can be obtained in JavaScript using the `.dataset` property so, `document.querySelector("#~").dataset.relative`

Comment: @ScottMarcus `innerText` has been [standardized](//github.com/rocallahan/innerText-spec) for a few years now.

Comment: yeah I edited it to use `.textContent` instead

Comment: It's not part of the W3C standard. It's in the WHATWG standard, but W3C is more authoritative. Read [this](https://www.w3.org/blog/2019/05/w3c-and-whatwg-to-work-together-to-advance-the-open-web-platform/) to see that there is an initiative for the two groups to work together under the W3C.

Comment: Also, `.innerText` and `.textContent` work differently. innerText doesn't include hidden content, while textContent does include it, and textContent includes other text that you wouldn't see on the page. See the [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText#examples) comparing them.

Comment: Thank you; I have updated my question, but still cannot capture the `data-relative` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the querySelector method to find the strong element within the div, and then use the textContent property to get the text within it. You can better understand.

Try this:

```
      // Get the div element
      const div = document.querySelector("div.pull-left.list-header");

      // Get the strong element within the div
      const strong = div.querySelector("strong");

      // Get the text within the strong element
      const text = strong.textContent;
      console.log(text);
```

You can use "for of" loop for all strong elements

```
      const strongs = document.querySelectorAll("div.list-header > strong");

      for (const strong of strongs) {
        const text = strong.textContent;
        console.log(text);
      }
```

Comment: Or just `document.querySelector("strong").textContent`.

Comment: Yes my way is long way

Comment: But `document.querySelector("strong")` will get the first `<strong>` element on the page, not necessarily the one within the `.list-header` div. Making barankibar's into a one-liner would be `document.querySelector('div.list-header > strong').textContent` (assuming there is only one `.list-header` in the page)

Answer (score 0):

for the first question i'd suggest using

```
document.querySelector(".list-header strong").textContent;
```

use `.getAttribute("data-relative")` to get the value of the attribute `"data-relative"`

or use `.dataset.relative` to get the value of the attribute `"data-relative"`

Comment: `closest` searches the ancestors of the element, not the descendants.

Comment: got you my bad edited it